# I want to change the color of dots to blue how it can be done?

Tags: matlab

The dots color remains white, I want to change the color of dots to blue.

```
function dotted()

    video = VideoWriter('Dotted-Line.avi'); 
    video.FrameRate = 100;
    video.Quality = 100;
    open(video);

    for r = 1:460
        I = zeros(500); 
        I(r+20,8:16:500) = 1;
        d = bwdist(I);
        imshow(d<2.5,'Border','tight');
        frame = getframe;
        writeVideo(video,frame);
    end

    close(video);
end
```

Comment: What dots are you referring to?

Comment: @Suever. The white dots. Near the spiders. What you mean you don't see them?

Answer (score 2):

You want to change the [`colormap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) of the figure (or axes in R2014b and later). By default `imshow` uses the grayscale colormap which will make your binary image black and white.

You can instead define a custom colormap of two values (black for 0 and blue for 1).

```
cmap = [0 0 0;   % Black
        0 0 1];  % Blue

imshow(d < 2.5);

colormap(gca, cmap)
```

[image]

Alternately, you can [specify the colormap directly to `imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html#inputarg_map). You'll have to add one to your binary data though since it needs to be an indexed image (starting at 1).

```
imshow((d < 2.5) + 1, cmap)
```